# The network location cannot be reached. Error code 0x800704cf. Windows 10

Tags: windows-networking

When I try to open windows store (OS Win 10) I get an error :
The network location cannot be reached. Error code 0x800704cf

However, I can open any website through browser Chrome/Opera/Edge without any delay. So, the internet is on but Windows store's server can not recognize it for some reason.

Comment: See this page....https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store-winpc/windows-store-error-0x800704cf/7cc8619e-8b75-4f84-a88f-131281ef2299

Comment: Have you used any applications that claimed to disable “spying” in Windows 10.  The error you received indicates that might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

- Run cmd as administrator.
- Insert command:  `ipconfig /flushdns` (& press Enter);
- Type next command `nbtstat -RR`  (& press Enter);
- Type : `netsh int ip reset`  (& press Enter);
- Reboot your laptop/PC.

If mistake start appearing again follow other steps [here](https://www.solutionbay.com/solutions/error-0x800704cf-the-network-location-cannot-be-reached-1). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating without the Microsoft Store? I was having a similar issue until I updated with the web download instead:
`wsl --update --web-download`

This command worked to update the wsl to the latest version.
The installation was failing for me because the Store could not connect to the internet due to the network saying "connected, no internet" even though there was a connection.

And then to install a new distro, try `wsl --install -d <distro> --web-download` or just leave the -d distro part out for default (Ubuntu).