# Solve the "The network location cannot be reached" issue without admin rights and restarting

Tags: windows, networking, network-drive, windows-networking

I have a similar problem as the one reported [here](https://superuser.com/q/1359557/588662), but I don't have admin rights, and neither I want to restart my computer.

At my company, many of our documents and software are on network drives. From time to time those network drives behave unpredictably. For example, the drive itself is shown as connected in Windows Explorer:

And when the drive is opened the folder structure is shown correctly:

However, if I try opening any of the folders I get this error message:

> Location is not available 
>  The network location can not be reached. For information about network troubleshooting see Windows Help.

Usually, we have to start once or twice and wait a long time before we login into the Operating System to make sure this will not happen. And that is very annoying if you are in the middle of a meeting or have so many unsaved works.

I would appreciate it if you could help me with a solution that **doesn't require**

- administrative privileges (it is a work computer and I can't / don't want to bother IT every time)
- restarting as suggested in the previous solution

I am ok with PowerShell or CMD/Batch solutions as far as they do not require any of the above. Preferably I can write and script that I can run any time this issue happens. Thanks for your kind support in advance.

Comment: Log out and log back in. That might work. Restarting a computer is a normal thing to do and I strongly suggest you re-think that. You may have to restart.

Comment: @John thanks for the response. but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. Restarting or religion is not a solution for me.

Comment: Strange.  Really strange.  Restarting is a normal activity. Updates coming in 5 days that will need restart.

Comment: @John I'm not sure what updates are you referring to? sure restarts are necessary every now and then. But if you have to do it every day, several times, in the middle of a meeting, or while you have much-unfinished work open, then it becomes a pain.

Comment: Patch Tuesday is this coming Tuesday. I do not have to restart every day. I control updates to run in off-hours so as not to impede my work in an way. The network connection issue should not occur very frequently in any event. Most of our client stay connected without issue.

Comment: @John we do not follow the latest updates as Microsoft releases them. in fact, we are still using 1803! We are using MS Office 2010!...

Comment: see if it's helpful to you https://www.techinpost.com/the-network-location-cannot-be-reached/